# Using sed to replace first n lines in a file with the first n lines from another file (say n=5)

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace lines from one file (*file1*) with the same number of lines and in same positions from another file(*file2*). I found

```
sed -n 1,5p file2
```

would extract the first five lines from *file2*.
How can i use these lines and replace the first five lines in *file1?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit of a cheat, (not pure `sed`), using [`sponge`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
{ sed -n 1,5p file2 ; sed -n '6,$p' file1 } | sponge file1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way to avoid sponge, i am working on a server and they don't seem to have moreutils installed

Comment: @Pavan, This should work: `{ sed -n 1,5p file2 ; sed -n '6,$p' file1 } > file3 ; mv file3 file1`

Answer (score 9):

For in-place editing with GNU `sed`, there's the `-i` option.  The *`R`ead line* command, (which reads one line from a named file, then each line after that when run again), is useful here.  Two line version:

```
sed -i '1,5{R file2
        d}' file1
```

Notes:

- `R`*ead line*'s output is not changed by the `d`*elete* that follows.  `R` inserts each line from *file2* **after** `d` deletes a line from *file1*.  The `d` cannot go first, (if it did, the `R` command would not be run, `d` is like `next` in `awk`)
- The `R`*ead line* (like all commands taking a file name) requires the filename be delimited by a linefeed.  The usual `;` command separator is ignored, `R` interprets `R file2;` as a filename ending with a literal "`;`".  The same with spaces, `R` interprets `R file2 ;` as a filename ending with a literal "`;`"
- `R` is not affected by `-i`, so *file2* won't be changed.

To fit that on *one line*, one can pass two `-e`xpressions which `sed` joins with linefeeds to form the `sed` script:

```
sed -i -e '1,5{R file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

Otherwise, you don't need `sed`:

```
{ head -n 5 file2; tail -n +6 file1; } > file3
```

In the general case, to replace `$x1` to `$y1` lines of `file1` with `$x2` to `$y2` lines of `file2`:

```
sed "$x2,\$!d;$y2 q" file2 | sed -i -e "$x1 r /dev/stdin" -e "$x1,$y1 d" file1
```

Or:

```
{
  head -n "$((x1 - 1))"
  tail -n "+$x2" < file2 | head -n "$((y2 - x2 + 1))"
  tail -n "+$((y1 - x1 + 2))"
} < file1 > file3
```

Comment: This is the best solution.  I've added some explanatory notes about the `R` command, since its syntax is not obvious or very well documented.

Comment: @agc - the `R` (just like `r`) doesn't operate on the pattern space - saying it's "immune to `d`" is a bit off imo... which brings us to your next statement: "_The `d` cannot go first, (if it does `R` outputs nothing);_". In fact, anything that follows after the `d` is no longer executed because `d` restarts the cycle. So if `R` comes after the `d` it cannot output "nothing" since it's not even executed. I'm not sure I get the part with  "_`R` is not affected by `-i`_" ...

Comment: Other working one line variants: `sed -i -e 1,5\{R\ file1 -e d\} file2` and `sed -i -e '1,5R file1' -e '1,5d' file2` and `sed -i -e 1,5R\ file1 -e 1,5d file2`.

Comment: @don_crissti, Thanks.  Prior to your useful comment I'd wrongly supposed that something like `seq 5 | sed '1{d;d}'` would not have output a `2`.  The bit about `-i` is to clarify that *in-place* edits do not change files only named by _`R`ead line_.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a tmp file?

```
sed -n ‘1,5p’ file2 > file3 ; sed ‘1,5d’ file1 >> file3 ; mv file3 file1
```

Comment: yeap, it works fine @agc has a similar solution